# How to put downloads from a certain site in a different folder?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, file-download

I know I can set the Downloads directory of Chrome, but I want to make a folder like `Downloads/My University` and put all the files downloaded from `*.myuniversity.edu` in that folder.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[QuickMove](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/quickmove-auto-move-files-to-a-folder-based-on-name-extension/) is one application that can take care of that.

Comment: Have you used this application before? Any problem with it?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams to be honest, I don't remember if I used this one or another one, because at the time, when I used an app like this, I was on a Mac, and I think it was Hazel (http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel)